# Setting same color of a category in both category plots

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am creating two category plots using Seaborn. One category plot has 6 categories whereas the second category plot has 5 categories to plot. There are 3 categories in both plots that are the same. I want to set up the same color for each of the categories that are common in both plots. I am using `sns.set_palette('coolwarm')` to set the color of both plots but the same categories in both plots have different colors. Is there any way of setting the same color of a category that appears in both plots?

Comment: Could you add some example code and toy data to show what you are doing exactly? Did you try the `hue_order=` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you put them together in a single dataframe and use `sns.catplot()` and separate your plots by using the `col=` argument :

```
np.random.seed(111)

d1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.randint(1,4,50),
                   'y':np.random.randn(50),
                   'z':np.random.choice(['a','b','c','d','e','f'],50),
                   'data':'d1'
                  })

d2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.randint(1,4,50),
                   'y':np.random.randn(50),
                   'z':np.random.choice(['d','e','f','g','h'],50),
                   'data':'d2'
                  })

df = pd.concat([d1,d2])
df['z'] = pd.Categorical(df['z'],ordered=True)

sns.catplot(data=df,x='x',y='y',hue='z',col='data',palette='coolwarm')
```

[image]

```
sns.catplot(data=df,x='x',hue='z',col='data',kind='count',palette='coolwarm')
```

[image]