# Use same colors per category in multiple plots in Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

[image]

You see two plots in one figure. The problem here is that the colors don't fit correctly. For exampel `A` is orange in the top plot and blue in the upper plot. My goal is to have `A` the same color in both plots and the same for `B`.`

I don't want to set explicit colors by name or hex values. I want to use that colors that the theme gives me. It seems to me that this theme here does use colors always in the same order: blue, orange, green, ...

Can I determine that order and the color values?
Can I modify that order plot specific?

For example if I know the first three colors I can know that `All` will have the first theme color. Because of that I can say that in the second plot the two box plots should use the second and third color in that color line.

Here is an MWE.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import pandas
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set_theme()

random.seed(0)

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'Group': random.choices(['A', 'B'], k=200),
    'Vals': random.choices(range(200), k=200)
})

a_and_b = df.copy()
a_and_b.Group = 'All'
df = pandas.concat([df, a_and_b])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

# plot All, A, B
sns.boxplot(
    ax=axes[0],
    data=df,
    y='Vals',
    x='Group',
    order=['All', 'A', 'B']
)

# # plot only A, B
sns.boxplot(
    ax=axes[1],
    data=df.loc[df.Group.ne('All')],
    y='Vals',
    x='Group',
    order=['A', 'B']
)

plt.show()
```

Comment: The easiest fix is to use `order=['A', 'B', 'All']` in the first plot.

Comment: Given **_I don't want to set explicit colors by name or hex values._**, then you can try `df.Group = pd.Categorical(df.Group, ['A', 'B', 'All'], ordered=True)` and remove `order=` from the plot call. As per [How can I match color palettes across different seaborn plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70385522/7758804) and [Setting same color of a category in both category plots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64584284/7758804). Otherwise you must use [match legend colors for two seaborn plots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67257674/7758804), and create a palette dict.

Comment: You could try a dictionary to be used as palette.  E.g. `colors=sns.color_palette('Set1'); my_palette={'All': colors[0], 'A': colors[1], 'B':colors[2]}` and `sns.boxplot(..., palette=my_palette)`.